# Fatal error: Call to undefined function _e() in ---- Wordpress plugin error

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

I'm following a tutorial in Wordpress for Developers. I started to debug the code and I am getting stuck here.
I think it might be a semi-colon? I'm not exactly sure.
 The code is as follows:

```
 <div class="wrap">
                <h2><?php _e( 'Halloween Store Options', 'halloween-plugin' ) ?></h2>
                <form method="post" action="options.php">
                    <?php settings_fields ( 'halloween-settings-group' ); ?>
                    <table class="form-table">
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Show Product Inventory', 'halloween-plugin' ); ?></th>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="halloween_options[show_inventory]" 
                                <?php echo checked( $hs_inventory, 'on' ); ?> /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Currency Sign', 'halloween-plugin' ) ?></th>
                            <td><input type="text" name="halloween_options[currency_sign]"
                                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $hs_currency_sign ); ?>"
                                size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" class="button-primary"
                        value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes', 'halloween-plugin' ); ?>" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How this file is loaded in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the file wp-load.php, before you use the function `_e()`.

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Comment: I tried loading wp-load.php, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out. My plugin header comments were on the same line as some code.